# Android How to tokenize a sentence

Tags: java, android

My code can tokenize the strings inputted, but when I inputted a string with spaces like a sentence, it cannot read the spaces. It can only read a word inputted...

Hopefully you understand what I am trying to do

```
public class AlphabetCompareClass extends Activity {
String get;
ImageView img;
int charIndex;
char[] getArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphabetcompare);
    Bundle gotWord = getIntent().getExtras();
    get = gotWord.getString("key");
    TextView Word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_alpha);
    Word.setText(get);

    getArray = get.toCharArray();

    charIndex = 0;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new ImageTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 2000);
};

public class ImageTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    ImageTimerTask imageTimerTask = this;

    @Override
    public void run() {
            System.out.println("charIndex: " + charIndex);
            System.out.println("this: " + getArray[charIndex]);
            System.out.println("get length: " + get.length());

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("run UI thread!");
                    InputStream is;
                    try {
                        is = getResources().getAssets().open(getArray[charIndex] + ".jpg");
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        charIndex++;

                        if(charIndex == get.length()){
                            System.out.println("cancel!");
                            imageTimerTask.cancel();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });


    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this, you can use this class to tokenize a given string : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html.. after you get individual tokens from here, you can call your tokenizer to each individual string emitted

Answer (score 1):

For this type of task I've used the split method of String

`String[] tokens = longerString.split(" ");`

Comment: I answered the question 'how to tokenise a sentence'.  The volume of code provided was long, uncommented, and not especially clear, so I settled on providing an answer useful for many, and not just fixing your code. :)